# How to get the ID of a button that is clicked and then use it as a Foreign Key for something else? (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Currently i have a simple program that receives user text input. The inputted text is then used as a heading for bootstrap collapsible's, these headings are referred to as 'Categories' within the context of my program. The user is able to click on any one of these categories and assign sub-categories (items) to them. However, i need to be able to record the ID of the category clicked (the category to which the user wishes to add sub-categorie(s) to), and then record this ID in a text file, as the foreign key of the sub-categorie(s) added.

It will work something like this:

1.) User clicks category 'Homework' (Has an ID (Primary Key) of 0)

2.) User adds several sub-categories, namely;

- 'Math Homework' (Has an ID (Primary Key) of 0, and Foreign key of 0)
- 'Biology' (Has an ID (Primary Key) of 1, and Foreign key of 0)
- 'French' (Has an ID (Primary Key) of 2, and Foreign key of 0)

3.) The text file in which the sub-categories are recorded will have the following format:

Math Homework,0,0

Biology,1,0

French,2,0

Note: As it stands, my text file is currently recording the first two parts of the above example, eg: it currently records: Math Homework,0 ... However i am struggling to link a Foreign Key.

Below is the view i am using to display the collapsibles:

```
@Model.CategoryList.result
        @if (Model.CategoryList.result == "")
        {
            int count = 0;

            foreach (String dataLine in Model.CategoryList.userData)
            {

                string countString = count.ToString();
                string target = "dataLine" + countString;
                string trigger = "#" + target;

                <p>
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="@trigger" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                        @dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[0]
                    </a>

                    <button class="btn" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Items", "Items")'" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[1]"><i class="fas fa-plus secondaryPlusIcon" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[1]"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[1]"><i class="far fa-edit secondaryEditIcon" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[1]"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[1]"><i class="far fa-trash-alt secondaryDeleteIcon" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[1]"></i></button>
                </p>

                foreach (String dataLineItem in Model.ItemList.userDataItems)
                {
                    <div class="collapse" id="@target">
                        <div class="card card-body w-25 p-3 collapsible" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[1]">
                            @dataLineItem.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[0]
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }

                count++;

            }

        }
```

As an additional side note; onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Items", "Items")'" is responsible for redirecting the user to a new view where he/she is able to enter the desired sub-categories.

And id="@dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[1]" assigns a unique accumulating integer ID, starting from 0, to each new category that is added. This would be the Primary Key for the category headers.

Lastly, here is the controller i have used to initialize the values seen within the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            CategoryItemViewModel CIVM = new CategoryItemViewModel();
            CIVM.ItemList = GetItemModel();
            CIVM.CategoryList = GetCategoryModel();
            return View(CIVM);             
        }

        public Category GetCategoryModel()
        {
            var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Category.txt");

            Category cModel = new Category()
            {
                result = "",
                delimiterChar = new[] { ',' },
                userData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dataFile) //Category Text File
            };

            return cModel;
        }

        public Item GetItemModel()
        {
            var dataFileItems = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Item.txt");

            Item iModel = new Item()
            {
                userDataItems = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dataFileItems) //Items Text File
            };

            return iModel;
        }
```

Hopefully i have provided sufficient information with the code and context mentioned above. I imagine one would use jQuery/AJAX/Json/JS etc to perform such a function, however i am quite lost on where to begin.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!